# Switch focused picture on a photo gallery on a timer

Tags: javascript, html, function

I'm trying to implement a timer that will swap the larger image with the next image in line, I feel like I'm on the right track, but I'm not getting there. I can't use Jquery or (event.target), (event.srcElement) or appendChild. Any ideas? I don't think my function is doing anything right now. Current code below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  <script>
  var aryImages[] = {"1.jpg", "2.jpg", "3.jpg"}
   function changeImage(varImage) {
    document.getElementById('bigImage').src='images/1.jpg';
    for (var i = 1; i < 4; i ++)
     index.html = "images/1.jpg" + photoOrder[i] +"sm.jpg";
   }
  </script>
  
  /* styling elements */
  <style>
   img
    {
     width: 300px;
     height: 290px;
     padding: 2px;
    }
   body
    {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 
 <body>
 <div>
  <img src="images/1.jpg" id="bigImage" />
 </div>
 <img src='images/1.jpg' id='image1' onclick="changeImage(image1)" />
 <img src='images/2.jpg' id='image2' onclick="changeImage(image2)"/>
 <img src='images/3.jpg' id='image3' onclick="changeImage(image3)"/>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: In the post you mentioned that you want a timer to switch the image, but in your HTML you are invoking a click handler. Do you want the swap to happen on click or via a timer?

Comment: user should be able to click images to change the image but if they don't then it will swap on a timer.

Comment: @bazzells do you know how to do any of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what you're looking for. I set an interval that will rotate through your images. If the user clicks an image, that will change the image and reset the interval.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Photo Gallery</title>
  <script>
                    var i = 1;
                    function changeImage(event, varImage) {
                        document.getElementById('bigImage').src='images/' + varImage + '.jpg';
                        // use this so the image interval doesnt 
                        // interfere with user's click
                        if (event !== null) {
                            clearInterval(newInt); 
                            newInt = setInterval(() => {
                                changeImage(null, i++);
                                if (i === 4) i = 1;
                            }, 500);
                        }
                     }
                     var newInt = setInterval(() => {
                         changeImage(null, i++);
                         if (i === 4) i = 1;
                     }, 500)
  </script>
  
  /* styling elements */
  <style>
   img
    {
     width: 300px;
     height: 290px;
     padding: 2px;
    }
   body
    {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
    }
  </style>
 </head>

 
 <body>
 <div>
  <img src="images/1.jpg" id="bigImage" />
 </div>
 <img src='images/1.jpg' id='1' onclick="changeImage(event, 1)" />
 <img src='images/2.jpg' id='2' onclick="changeImage(event, 2)"/>
 <img src='images/3.jpg' id='3' onclick="changeImage(event, 3)"/>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Images swap really nicely but still can't click on any of them though. :/

Comment: My mistake, I'm passing the wrong value as "id". Should be "1","2". Not "image1", "image2".

Comment: Updated to do so.

Answer (score 0):

first of all you are not changing anything

you dont have a timer at all :)
here how to implement one:

```
setInterval(function(){ 
    // do something;
}, 3000);
```

now inside the timer you should change images

for example 
you should run inspect element on image to see changes because there is no images at these sources

```js
var images = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg'];
    var currentImage = 0;
    // assuming that image is the image index in the array.
    
    var changeImage = function (image) {
        document.getElementById('bigImage').src = 'images/' + images[image];
    };
    
    // now we can use setInterval function
    setInterval(function(){ 
        // check if we reached the last image
        if(currentImage >= images.length -1) {
            // if last image go back to first one
            currentImage = 0;
        } else {
            // if not last image so give me the next
            currentImage ++;
        }
        // do the image change
        changeImage(currentImage);
    }, 3000);
```

```html
<img src="images/image1.jpg" id="bigImage" />

<button onclick="changeImage(0)" > image1 </button>
<button onclick="changeImage(1)" > image2 </button>
<button onclick="changeImage(2)" > image3 </button>
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you're telling me to put these snippets.

Comment: ah ok
in your javascript file
or wherever you write javascript|| or just replace it with your javascript